# Arraylist and Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

How do I put two different objects from two different classes which inherit from the same super class in one single array list?

Comment: Make an arraylist of superclass. You can put instances of subclass in this ArrayList.

Comment: Sir - this is basic Java question. Some googling would definitely help your cause.

Comment: Create a new arraylist of the superclass like so:

ArrayList<Superclass> list = new ArrayList<Superclass>();

Then continue to add any instances of any of the subclasses like so:

list.Add(subclass);

Comment: Use generic ArrayList<? extends superclass>. or simply Arraylist (bydefault Object);

Comment: @Prashant You just suggested to use a raw types? Yikes.

Comment: @Tom: generic type can be used here thats what i suggested.

Comment: @Prashant so someone else wrote `or simply Arraylist (bydefault Object);`?

Comment: @Tom Arraylist arr= new Arraylist (); can hold any object that what i meant..

Comment: @Prashant And that is why it should be avoided ... *always*. Raw types are an absolute no-go.

Comment: @Tom : i knew that, but simply i said that (my mistake).

Comment: Well, you could re-write that comment, without the "raw type" part and we can delete this little discussion :).

Answer (score 8):

```
List<Parent> listValue = new ArrayList<Parent>();
listValue.add(new Child1());
listValue.add(new Child2());
```

Both Child1 and Child2 are inherited from "Parent" Class.

Answer (score 3):

You can look java library classes for this.
For example Shape class is superclass of Rectangle and Polygon classes

```
ArrayList<Shape> list = new ArrayList<Shape>();
list.add(new Rectangle());
list.add(new Polygon());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating "ArrayList" of super class.
Than you can add the child class elements in the "ArrayList".

```
List<SuperClass> tempList=new ArrayList<SuperClass>();
tempList.add(childClass1);
tempList.add(childClass2);
```

Hope this solves your problem.